# JQ duplicate elements in array based on values from second array

Tags: json, jq

In JQ, I would like to duplicate elements n-times in the first array based on the values of the second array. As seen in the example below I would like to have the first element of the first array two times and the second element of the array three times. The number of elements are different in each case.

```
[["1/optimized/17853791_fpx.tif", "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif"],
["2", "3"]]
```

The desired output should look like:

```
["1/optimized/17853791_fpx.tif", "1/optimized/17853791_fpx.tif", "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif", "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif", "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif"]
```

I tried out some things but couldn't figure it out..

Comment: What does this have to do with [jquery](https://jquery.com/)?

Comment: Is the second array always present as part of the first one? or does it have a different input source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A transpose-free solution:

```
[. as [$x, $n] 
 | range(0;$n|length) as $i 
 | range(0;$n[$i]|tonumber)|$x[$i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a  solution using `transpose`, `limit` and `repeat`:

```bash
jq 'transpose | map(limit(last | tonumber; repeat(first)))' file.json
```

```json
[
  "1/optimized/17853791_fpx.tif",
  "1/optimized/17853791_fpx.tif",
  "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif",
  "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif",
  "3/optimized/17853793_fpx.tif"
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fXKh4Yjgff-)

Answer (score -1):

```
def r($in;n): range(0;n)|$in;

.[1] |= map(tonumber)
| transpose
| map(r(first;last))
```